# Save image from URL with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I need to save an image from url directly to my server, i've tried many methods but all seems doesn't work properly. `file_put_contents($file_location, file_get_contents($image_url));` keeps me getting no file directory found error. Simple `fopen` and `fwrite` keeps returning corrupted image. This one worked, but it keeps returning html file instead of jpg file.

```
function getimg($url) {         
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';         
    $process = curl_init($url);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);         
    $return = curl_exec($process);         
    curl_close($process);         
    return $return;     
} 

$imgurl = 'http://some/url/to/image.jpg'; 
$imagename= basename($imgurl);
if(file_exists('./image/'.$imagename)){continue;} 
$image = getimg($imgurl); 
file_put_contents('image/'.$imagename,$image);
```

Something is missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's an image file you're trying to download and not a web page? What does the HTML file you get contain?

Answer (score 3):

Your code works correct. It downloads the image from the given url.

Your issue will be in the path where the image is stored.

```
if(file_exists('./image/'.$imagename)){continue;} 
$image = getimg($imgurl); 
file_put_contents('image/'.$imagename,$image);
```

In the above code check the path ./image/ and give the path as in the file_put_contents path.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i've found the solution, the URL(image name) has 'space' char, so i have to replace them with '%20'. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

This method works:

```
<?php

file_put_contents("/var/www/test/test.png", file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"));

?>
```

You need to enable `allow_url_fopen` and it's the simplest method. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php